# SQL Function to create Row Number Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to create a function in SQL and put it into computed column?
The idea is this function is to create a row number group by some column. For example:

```
ID    Name    DateTimeCreated        ComputedColumn_RowNumber
1     A       2017-06-01 06:00:00    1
2     B       2017-06-01 07:00:00    2
3     C       2017-06-02 06:00:00    1
4     D       2017-06-03 08:00:00    1
5     E       2017-06-03 09:00:00    2
```

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/92165402-b262-472e-88a8-cc845845d00e/rownumber-for-a-computed-column?forum=transactsql)?

Comment: Why do you want it in a computed column? Why not just put a rownum into a view?

Comment: @under, there's no reason. I am just asking, is it possible or not?

Comment: @HoneyBadger, Hi.. I didn't see that. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the something like:

```
SELECT ID, Name, DateTimeCreated, row_number() OVER (partition by DateTimeCreated order by DateTimeCreated) as CalculatedRowNumber FROM myTable
```